# Are res/req keywords or can you name them whatever you want to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Referring to response and request in express methods.

Comment: they are function arguments and you can name them whatever you want but the order matter

Comment: They're ordinary function parameters, you can name them however you like, or even omit them if you don't want to use them.

Comment: If you want anyone that is experienced with Express to understand or work on your code, I'd suggest you leave them as `res` and `req` as that's what most people know of that architecture.  When people change them and I'm trying to help them with their code I suddenly feel like I'm in a foreign land and am unsure what the new variable names actually represent when I see them in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can name it whatever you want, but req, res and next are the Express defaults. I recommend you to use it with that same syntax but it will note broke your app if not :)